# Jena; listDeclaredProperties semantics

Tags: jena, owl, pellet

Let's consider a

```
(1) P Domain CSuper
(2) CSub subClassOf CSuper
```

Using Jena, I'm trying to list the declared properties for `CSub`. What I believe is that `P` mustn't be listed as a declared property for `CSub`. My justification: `P` is a declared property for `CSub`, **iff** `CSub` is a domain for `P`, from (1) `CSuper` is a domain for `P` which doesn't imply that `CSub` is also a domain; (1) means that if `(x, y)` is `P`, then `x` is `CSuper`, clearly `x` may **(not)** be `CSub`.

The surprising thing is that Jena is listing `P` as a declared property for `CSub` when using `listDeclaredProperties` method even using OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF or Pellet! **Am I missing something?**

**Update:**
What does a declared property for some class mean? Does it mean the classes that the property is a domain of them!

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
theClass.listDeclaredProperties(false);
```

From [the documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html#listDeclaredProperties%28%29):

> `listDeclaredProperties()` Equivalent to calling listDeclaredProperties(boolean) with default value direct = false.
>
> `direct` - If true, restrict the properties returned to those directly associated with this class. If false, the properties of super-classes of this class will not be listed among the declared properties of this class.

I think you've misunderstood declared properties. This returns properties that a class may (or must) have. Suppose we have a class hierarchy:

```
A > B > C
```

and also:

```
P domain B
```

All `Bs` and `Cs` may have property `P` -- no contradiction there. However it's not true that all `As` may have property `P` -- the `not-Bs` are the problem.

Comment: Well, this seems clear. However, what does a declared property for some class mean? Does it mean the classes that the property is a domain of them? If this is true, then all As and Bs will have the P, i.e. not all Bs and Cs!

Comment: In RDF schema it will simply mean domain, I think. (I'm not sure whether it includes properties without an explicit domain) OWL may be more complex, I can't recall.